# Как разделить ссылки по нескольким блокам, шириной во всю страницу, для возможности "перелистывания" этих блоков?

Tags: html, css

Есть меню, которое открывается на полный экран.
[image: Меню]

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(127deg, #ff6666, #902999);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Теперь добавим несколько ссылок:
[image: Меню с несколькими ссылками]

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(127deg, #ff6666, #902999);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#menu .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

#menu .content a {
  margin: 1rem 0;
 padding: 0.85rem 1rem;
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">Ссылка</a>
        <a href="">Ссылка</a>
        <a href="">Ссылка</a>
        <a href="">Ссылка</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Пока что все нормально и работает как надо. Но давайте добавим намного больше ссылок (сколько их будет - не знаю).

[image: Больше ссылок]

Теперь ссылки не вмещаются. Попробуем использовать `flex-wrap: wrap;`, чтобы невмещающиеся ссылки "перекидывались" направо.

[image: flex-flow: column wrap;]

Ссылки, которые не влезали, действительно переместились правее. Теперь ограничим высоту блока, чтобы тот занимал до 80% от доступной высоты.

[image: Ограничили высоту]

Получилось. Теперь **вопрос**. Как добиться того, чтобы ссылки перекидывались ровно настолько дальше, насколько это нужно для того, чтобы в будущем можно было просто нажать кнопку вправо и те ссылки оказались бы по центру. Подробнее: открыл меню - 4 (например) ссылки (на самом деле, столько, сколько может влезть). Нажал на стрелку - страница "передвинулась", теперь видны 4 новые ссылки. Перелистнул еще - видны оставшиеся, например, 3 (тоже оцентрированные вертикально).

**Что пытался сделать я**: я установил `overflow: hidden;` родителю ссылок, чтобы полосы горизонтальной прокрутки видно не было. Далее я добавил 100%-ую ширину ссылке (в надежде на то, что остальные сдвинутся на всю ширину меню). Вот, что получил.

[image: 100% ширина ссылок]

Это не то поведение, которое мне надо. Дело в том, что ссылки теперь занимают 100% ширину, а ширина рамок (сделаны с использованием `::before` и `::after`) зависит именно от ширины ссылки. Соответственно рамки будут занимать всю ширину, в то время как тест ссылки может быть всего 10 символов длиной. Ставить на костыли рамки **недопустимо** по определенным причинам.

Собственно говоря, можно было бы поместить каждую группу ссылок в отдельный контейнер, ширина которого зависела бы от длины ссылок. Но я **не знаю, сколько ссылок будет в контейнере**, так как это количество зависит напрямую от доступной контейнеру высоты. *Облом*.

Итог: как разместить ссылки, оцентрированные горизонтально и вертикально, в несколько столбцов, чтобы при горизонтальном перелистывании можно было добавить контейнеру со ссылками `margin-left: -100%;` (или что-то типа того) средствами JS и блок ссылок бы "провернулся" на доступную контейнеру ширину?

### ***UPD.***

Приведу более понятный пример.
Представьте, что вы на каком-нибудь сайте нажали на фото и оно открылось в полный размер. Фото заняло 100% ширины экрана (браузера) и 100% высоты. После этого вы захватили его [фото] мышкой, потянули влево, перетащив тем самым новую фотографию. Теперь новая фотография заняла 100% ширины и высоты.

У меня та же самая ситуация, но:

1. Вместо фотографии - n-ное количество ссылок.
2. Количество ссылок зависит от высоты экрана (на одном мониторе поместится 10 ссылок, на другом - 5).
3. Ссылки должны быть оцентрированы по вертикали и по горизонтали.
4. Те ссылки, что не поместились на экран, переносятся в другую колонку. Но другая колонка тоже должна занимать 100% ширины и 80% (пускай 100%) высоты.
5. При смахивании одной колонки со ссылками в сторону, должна, как фотография, выезжать новая колонка.

Проблема: вопрос заключается в следующем: как поделить ссылки на блоки (1) (частично решен с помощью flex-wrap)? Как разместить второй (третий, четвертый) блок со ссылками на таком расстоянии от предыдущего, чтобы при перелистывании новый блок был по центру? Аналогия: в ряд стоят 4 монитора (одинаковых). Первый блок - на первом мониторе, второй - на втором (и т.д.). Вот только мне нужно разместить эти блоки на одном мониторе, как будто бы друг за другом. Причем стоит учесть, что, если пользователь "стянул" окно браузера, то в блоке из 4-х ссылок останется 3. Соответственно, если было 4 блока по 4 ссылки, то после их перемещения, должно стать 5 блоков по 3 ссылки и еще один с одной ссылкой.

Надеюсь, теперь стало понятнее.

Comment: Самый большой вопрос, который я тут видел, и дважды прочитав всеравно не понятно что в итоге хотите получить. тут без фидла и рисунка не обойтись

Comment: Вот такой вариант: список ссылок сделать тегами `<ul>` и `<li>`. `<li>`  назначить ширину 100%, а внутри них отцентровать `<a>` уже с имеющимися рамками

Comment: Что-то вроде слайдера для меню применить.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вы делаете рамки псевдоэлементами?

Comment: @tutankhamun как вариант неплохо. Надо будет протестировать.

Comment: @tutankhamun для эффектов. Не берите в голову.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev конкретизировал, привел аналогии, дополнил, разжевал. Рисовать, к сожалению, не умею, а если бы мог филд сделать, то вопрос бы не задавал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вам все равно делать листалку на JS, вы можете разбивать ссылки на слайды по количеству или по высоте средствами JS.

Но как вариант можно сделать и так:

```js
$('#prev, #next').on('click', function(e) {
  var el = $('.content'),
   step = $('#menu').width(),
    leftLim = -$('li', el).last().position().left,
    leftNew;
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.target).is('#next')) {
   step = -step;
  }
  leftNew = Math.floor((el.position().left - step) / step) * step;
  leftNew = Math.min(leftNew, 0);
  leftNew = Math.max(leftNew, leftLim);
 el.css({left: leftNew});
});
```

```css
#prev,
#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
#prev {
  left: 80px;
}
#next {
  right: 80px;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(127deg, #ff6666, #902999);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}
#menu .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 20;
  width: auto;
}
#menu .content li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu .content li a {
  padding: 0.85rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu .content li a:before {
  background: red;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="prev">««</div>
  <div id="next">»»</div>
  <ul class="content">
    <li><a href="">Ссылка1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка3333</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка5555555</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка77</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка8</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```